# Case of "leo" in Judges 14:5

Tags: vulgata

[Judges 14:5](http://www.drbo.org/lvb/chapter/07014.htm) in the Vulgata reads:

> Descendit itaque Samson cum patre suo et matre in Thamnatha. Cumque venissent ad vineas oppidi, **apparuit catulus leonis** saevus, et rugiens, et occurrit ei.

I don't under the declension of *leo* above (genitive, *leonis*). The young lion appeared to Samson, so why is it not in accusative case? Or is the above actually saying something like "a young animal of lion [type] appeared [to Samson]"?

Contrast the above verse with other uses of *leo* in the same chapter, using the "correct" case:

- Accusative in Judges 14:6

  > Irruit autem spiritus Domini in Samson, et **dilaceravit leonem**, quasi haedum in frustra discerpens, nihil omnino habens in manu : et hoc patri et matri noluit indicare
- Genitive in Judges 14:8

  > Et post aliquot dies revertens ut acciperet eam, declinavit ut videret **cadaver leonis**, et ecce examen apum in **ore leonis** erat ac favus mellis.

Comment: >"The young lion appeared to Samson" If this is the translation you expect, why would you expect accusative at all?

Comment: @eques Correct. I got confused there (but still, the nominative is not used).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Leonis* is in the genitive case and paired with [*catulus*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dcatulus1) (= "young of an animal" or "whelp"). *Catulus leonis* simply means **"the whelp of a lion"**, i.e. a lion kitten.

Lucretius uses a similar construction in the plural:

> at **catuli pantherarum scymnique leonum**
>   unguibus ac pedibus iam tum morsuque repugnant,
>   vix etiam cum sunt dentes unguesque creati. (*De Rerum Natura* 5.1036-38.)

*Catulus* is the subject of *apparuit* and thus is in the nominative case. The last sentence translates as follows:

> When they came to the vineyards of the city, a fierce, raging young lion appeared and went to meet him [i.e. Samson].

Answer (score 4):

Your supposition is correct:

> Or is the above actually saying something like "a young animal of lion
>   [type] appeared [to Samson]"?

The subject is *catulus* as indicated by its being in the nominative, and it is of the type *leonis* in the genitive.